# Many-to-Many hibernate mapping and mysql script - persistence problem

Tags: mysql, hibernate, mapping, many-to-many

#### For some reason this is not persisting anything into tag_item table :

```
    Tag tag = new Tag();
    tag.setName("test");
    tag = (Tag) tagService.save(tag);

    Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    tags.add(tag);

    Item item = itemService.getByStringId(2);
    item.setTags(tags);
    itemService.save(item);
```

#### MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
`tag_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `tag_item` (
`tag_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`tag_id`),
KEY `FK_tag_item_tag_id` (`tag_id`),
KEY `FK_tag_item_item_id` (`item_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_tag_item_tag_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`tag_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_tag_item_item_id` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `items`    (`item_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `items` (
`item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

#### Xml Hibernate Mappings:

```
<id name="id" type="long" column="tag_id">
        <generator class="native"/>
</id>
    <property name="name" type="string" column="name"/>
    <set name="items" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="tag_item">
        <key>
              <column name="tag_id" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <many-to-many class="com.iteezy.shared.domain.Item">
              <column name="item_id" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

---

```
<id name="id" type="long" column="item_id">
        <generator class="native"/>
</id>
    <property name="name" type="string" column="name"/>
    <set name="tags" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="tag_item">
        <key>
              <column name="item_id" not-null="true"/>
        </key>
        <many-to-many class="com.iteezy.shared.domain.Tag">
              <column name="tag_id" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

Comment: I hate xml mapping files, so I don't have an answer to your question. But this annotations mapping is wrong : one of the side of the associations should use mappedBy="tags" (or "posts"), and should thus not have @JoinTable and @ForeignKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bidiectional many-to-many relationship, so you can use an example in [8.5.3. Many-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-m2m). Also see [7.3.1. Sorted collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted) for the way to configure a comparator (though it would be better to perform sorting at the database side with `order-by`).